# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 when i run 'ionic cordova emulate ios' on my ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using [cordova-plugin-facebook4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook4) on version 1.10.1. When i run `ionic cordova emulate ios` I'm getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:


"___isOSVersionAtLeast", referenced from:
      -[FBSDKApplicationDelegate application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:] in FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKApplicationDelegate.o)
      -[FBSDKApplicationDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive:] in FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKApplicationDelegate.o)
      -[FBSDKApplicationDelegate openURLWithSafariViewController:sender:fromViewController:handler:] in FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKApplicationDelegate.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

When I remove the cordoba-plugin-facebook4 the command `ionic cordova emulate ios` works. I'm using Xcode 8 because my mac OS is 10.11.6 and my machine is too old to upgrade the Mac OS. I will put bellow my execution ambient:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.2.1
   @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.7

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : ios 4.4.0
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (13 plugins total)

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   NodeJS     : v6.14.4
   npm        : 3.10.10
   OS         : OS X El Capitan
   Xcode      : Xcode 8.0 Build version 8A218a

iOS SDKs:
    iOS 10.0                        -sdk iphoneos10.0

iOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - iOS 10.0            -sdk iphonesimulator10.0

macOS SDKs:
    macOS 10.12                     -sdk macosx10.12

tvOS SDKs:
    tvOS 10.0                       -sdk appletvos10.0

tvOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - tvOS 10.0           -sdk appletvsimulator10.0

watchOS SDKs:
    watchOS 3.0                     -sdk watchos3.0

watchOS Simulator SDKs:
    Simulator - watchOS 3.0         -sdk watchsimulator3.0
```

Thanks for any help guys!

Comment: Did you found the solution?